# Batman Arkham City Watcher in the Wings side mission is impossible?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I have recently started the Watcher in the Wings side mission. I have found all four locations for Azrael and found his final location, but I didn't scan the symbol behind him. Now, when I try to scan the symbol again, it says symbol already scanned and it is now impossible for me to complete the side mission. I've tried restarting the XBox, but it didn't help. I really don't want to restart the game, since I have all Riddler trophies and riddles solved. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

"Scanning the fourth symbol that the watcher leaves behind will automatically take you to the Batcomputer screen. Use the right and left sticks to rotate and move the sigil

> so that its four points match the four locations in which you spotted the watcher.

> Doing so reveals the watchers final location: the eastern side of the church. Scan the symbol on the wall there to complete this side mission."

http://www.gamesradar.com/batman-arkham-city-watcher-wings-side-mission-guide/

If you have yet to get to the part where you "rotate and move the sigil" on "the Batcomputer screen", maybe you can get to it by highlighting the side mission in "the Batcomputer screen". If you've already got to the part where you "rotate and move the sigil" but couldn't get any further, read the spoiler. Read the second spoiler if you want to know how to complete the rest of the side mission.